# Google Custom Search gives different result number for same query

Tags: c#, .net, api

we are getting different results in custom search API than normal Google search. One Normal Google search gives around 600000 results but for the same search parameter custom API gives 300000 results with different order.

Can anybody guide us how to get same results as Normal google search using custom API ?

Comment: A) this is google we are talking about, who knows what weird things they do B) you have shown no examples or code and nothing reproducible C) if you have an issue with googles inconsistent responses, the people you should be asking is seemingly google.

Comment: 300,000 vs 600,000 seems somewhat of a moot point. No-one looks past page 5. Certainly not to page 300,001.